# How much mass would be spilled from a bucket?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

I am working with the equation of a conveyor belt system with buckets, where $\beta$ is the damper and $k$ the spring constant:

$$m \frac{ \mathrm{d}^2 x}{ \mathrm{d} t^2} + \beta \frac{ \mathrm{d} x }{ \mathrm{d} t} + kx = 0 $$

What I would like to find is a model where we can work out how much mass is lost every time we drop mass into the bucket.

As the conveyor belt moves along at a steady speed, what would the loss be from dropping mass in the bucket?

Comment: second-order homogeneous ODE, use the characteristic equation, what does mass being lost mean in this context?

Comment: As in, we dump an x amount of say dirt into the bucket, how much of that will be lost?